# Kubernetes services deployed via Terraform's local-exec not destroyed when applying "terraform destroy"

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I would like template my Kubernetes manifests via Terraform and perform a `kubectl apply` from the `local-exec` provisioner.

Everything seemed to work perfectly until I realized that the resources (services & deployments) were in fact not destroyed by the `terraform apply`.

Manifests are templated and applied this way:

```
data "template_file" "service_template" {
  count    = length(var.services)

  template = file("${path.module}/templates/${lookup(var.services[count.index], "name")}.tpl")
  
  vars = {
    cluster_name = var.cluster_name
    tag          = lookup(var.services[count.index], "tag")
  }
}

resource "local_file" "template" {
  count    = length(var.services)

  content  = data.template_file.service_template[count.index].rendered
  filename = "${path.module}/deployments/${lookup(var.services[count.index], "name")}.yaml"
}


resource "null_resource" "apply" {
  count    = length(var.services)

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f ${path.module}/deployments/${lookup(var.services[count.index], "name")}.yaml --kubeconfig config_file_path"
  }
}
```

I wanted to generate the manifests in order to be able to easily manage my services/deployments by hand if needed.

Did someone deploy manifests like this and managed to have a clean state after destroying ?

Or the only solution would by to use `kubernetes_service` & `kubernetes_deployment` resources ?

**Edit:**

I tried to use a local-exec provisioner with an `on_destroy` value assigned to `when` but came accross references errors:

```
Destroy-time provisioners and their connection configurations may only
reference attributes of the related resource, via 'self', 'count.index', or
'each.key'.

References to other resources during the destroy phase can cause dependency
cycles and interact poorly with create_before_destroy.
```

Comment: Have you seen https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes-alpha/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_manifest? That would give you a better option for managing the lifecycle of manifest files.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see it and it could fit my needs ! 
I copy this interesting link aswell: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/deploy-any-resource-with-the-new-kubernetes-provider-for-hashicorp-terraform

Comment: @ydaetskcoR An issue with this way of managing manifests is that I don't see how I could dynamically deploy services given the fact that the manifests would be hardcoded inside Terraform as HCL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a destroy time provisioner

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#destroy-time-provisioners